# What are the, if any, Tooling API Limits?

Tags: limits, tooling-api

What are the, if any, Tooling API Limits? I can't find any info on it. I checked in the docs, but no word of it, unless i'm just missing them.

Thanks

Comment: I think those fall under the general API limits.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Someone suggested to me that there might be a diff set of limits for them. Thanks

Comment: @MikeChale if that is the answer, post it as the answer so it can be accepted and upvoted!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think those fall under the general API limits but can't find any hard confirmations.

Looking at the current [Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide](https://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) (Summer '13), page 31 under API Limits:

> API Limits for concurrent and total API requests, bulk API operations, API cursors, and limits on some selected APIs.

In addition:

1. The [Tooling Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf) just mentions using either a REST or SOAP-based API and does not mention any limits.
2. The Analytics API's limits fall under the general API limits ([Winter '14 Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf), page 170)